# What is OpenWRT? how can we use it?

Tags: linux, networking, internet, openwrt

What is OpenWRT? How can I make a small network to host my websites?
I have searched a lot around the Web but didn't find anything. I hope someone can help me this regard.

Comment: They have a website - https://openwrt.org/ - and also at Wikipedia with all the information you need. It's mostly a routers' firmware replacement with added features but AFAIK not designed for web server.

Answer (score 2):

OpenWRT is an operating system for routers, not meant for regular PCs, and will not help you host your web site.

If you want to host your website, you need to a couple of things:

1. A web server reachable by the general public. You can install one yourself, e.g. Apache 2.4 or Nginx on Windows or Linux and any Software you may need. The term `LAMP stack` may help you search for more information.
2. An address to reach. This may be a domain name you purchase (e.g. example.com), but behind it you need a static IP address, that can be linked to such an address via a public DHCP server.
3. If you can't afford a public IP, you can use DynDNS and use a registrar to publish your DNS information with a link to your DynDNS address and host it at home.

The easy way: Rent a web server  on one of the many sites that offer this kind of service. My website is hosted in a professional data center with 99% availability and it costs 3€ a month. Setting up your own hosting is far more expensive and requires serious know-how, which you seem to lack.